# Using DetailView to view UserProfiles in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I need help with simple blog site. Where users can write Posts. Each Post writer has to signed in to write a Post. But the reader does not have to be signed in.

I am using django DetailView to allow readers to view Profiles of the Post writers.

The Profile View will have details of the writers along with other Posts the writer has written.

I used the below logic to make the view
https://chriskief.com/2012/12/29/django-generic-detailview-without-a-pk-or-slug/

Below are the Details:

All this is in the accounts app in my site. The below code is broken and give a  error

[Image of the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD1tU.jpg)

accounts/views.py:

```
    class ProfileView(DetailView):
            model = User
            template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'

            def get_user_profile(self, username):   
                return get_object_or_404(User, pk=username)
     #I know pk=username is not correct. I am not sure what to put pk=?

  # I was able to get the writers other posts using the code below. I did not have to show this code for this question. But just to show you that the pk above has to be username. Or Else the code below won't work(I guess)        
            def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
                context['post_list'] = Post.objects.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
                return context
```

My models are as below

accounts/models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        bio = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
        profile_image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, null='')


        def __str__(self):
            return "Profile of {}".format(self.user.username)
```

Below is my Template

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block body %}
    <div class="content">
        <h1>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h1>
        <p>            
            <br/>From: City, Country
            <br/>Bio
            <br/>Profile Image
        </p>
    </div>


    {% endblock %}
```

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),

]
```

ERROR MESSAGE TEXT

AttributeError at /accounts/profile/3/
Generic detail view ProfileView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/3/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
Generic detail view ProfileView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django-1.11-py3.6.egg\django\views\generic\detail.py in get_object, line 49
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path:.........

Comment: What's your Question, here?

Comment: def get_user_profile(self, username):   
                return get_object_or_404(User, pk=username)
The above code does not work pk = username is not correct

Comment: Are you sure you want a `DetailView` here? A `DetailView` is meant for displaying details of a single object. What is the object you want to display? Inside the `get_user_profile` method, you can get the logged in/anonymous user with `self.request.user`.

Comment: I am absolutely open to changing that If there is a alternative
Below is where I got that Idea from:
https://chriskief.com/2012/12/29/django-generic-detailview-without-a-pk-or-slug/

Comment: If you are new to Django, pls go with FunctionBasedViews instead of using ClassBasedViews

Comment: @Alasdair I get the same error message with self.request.user

Comment: Please copy and paste the error text instead of linking to images. You haven't my other question: A DetailView is meant for displaying details of a single object. What is the object you want to display? It looks like this is really a list view to display a list of posts by the user with `username`.

Comment: @ramganesh I tried function based view below: but I cannot (don't know how to) insert the code which shows the Writers other posts

def get_user_profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'user':user})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(?, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post_list'] = Post.objects.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return context

what to add in pace of "?"

Comment: @Alasdair I have added the error message as text like you requested. I did answer your question. The reason I used a Detail View is the link below:

 https://chriskief.com/2012/12/29/django-generic-detailview-without-a-pk-or-slug/ 

I am open to all open alternatves

Comment: @Alasdair I am sorry if I am annoying you I am new to Django and trying to answer your questions to the best of my knowledge and abiity:

I am trying to display the User Profile. Example if a writer wrote a Post .Clicking on the writers name will take the Anonymous user to the Writers Profile.

Comment: OK, so your question says "DetailView to allow readers to view Profiles of the Post writers" - that confused me because it made it sound like you wanted to display multiple profiles on one detail view. If you want to display a single profile then `DetailView` is OK. You want to override `get_object` as Marcos suggests. The post you linked to was confusing as well, because that explains how to display details for the logged-in user. But you want to display the profile for the user with `username` from the URL, not for the logged-in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the 'username' field to get the User, you may want to 
change the filter to use the 'username' field, since it's unique:

Try change the function:

```
def get_user_profile(self, username):   
    return get_object_or_404(User, pk=username)
```

to

```
def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

OR

If you want the object to be the UserProfile, then change it slightly to

```
def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user__username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

Comment: Thats the 1st thing I had done I got the image as shown in the image above

Comment: Which image? And where did you use the 'get_user_profile' function. What are the content of the argument 'username' (str)?

Comment: I used the below logic to make the view 
https://chriskief.com/2012/12/29/django-generic-detailview-without-a-pk-or-slug/

Comment: Click on the link that says: Image of the Error Message

Comment: I see. Try change the function name 'get_user_profile' to 'get_object' and remove the 'pk' argument on the filter to 'username'.
E.g:
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))

Comment: trying this now

Comment: If you want the object to be the `UserProfile`, then change it slightly to `get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user__username=self.kwargs['username'])`.

Comment: Yes that did work. Awesome thnks for being so patient